# How to do date range filter on jquery datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery data tables.
I am doing date range filter on it. When i select min date and max date result is no data filtered on data tables.
I used the script

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table1 = $('#sample_2').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print',
    ]
  });

  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
      //var min = $('#min').datepicker("getDate");
      // var max = $('#max').datepicker("getDate");
      var min = $('#min').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
      }).val();
      var max = $('#max').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
      }).val();
      //console.log(min);
      console.log(min);
      console.log(max);
      //var startDate = new Date(data[4]);
      var today = new Date();
      var dd = today.getDate();
      var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!

      var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
      if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
      }
      if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
      }
      var today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
      var startDate = today;
      console.log(startDate);

      if (min == null && max == null) {
        return true;
      }
      if (min == null && startDate <= max) {
        return true;
      }
      if (max == null && startDate >= min) {
        return true;
      }
      if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  );


  $("#min").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
      table1.draw();
    },
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
  });
  $("#max").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
      table1.draw();
    },
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
  });

  // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
  $('#min, #max').change(function() {
    table1.draw();
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table1 = $('#sample_2').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print',
    ]
  });

  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
      //var min = $('#min').datepicker("getDate");
      // var max = $('#max').datepicker("getDate");
      var min = $('#min').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
      }).val();
      var max = $('#max').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
      }).val();
      //console.log(min);
      console.log(min);
      console.log(max);
      //var startDate = new Date(data[4]);
      var today = new Date();
      var dd = today.getDate();
      var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!

      var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
      if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd;
      }
      if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm;
      }
      var today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
      var startDate = today;
      console.log(startDate);

      if (min == null && max == null) {
        return true;
      }
      if (min == null && startDate <= max) {
        return true;
      }
      if (max == null && startDate >= min) {
        return true;
      }
      if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  );


  $("#min").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
      table1.draw();
    },
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
  });
  $("#max").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
      table1.draw();
    },
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
  });

  // Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
  $('#min, #max').change(function() {
    table1.draw();
  });
});
```

The date format is yyyy-mm-dd.
Every time i search with date range result is not coming in datatables.
Please help me where am i doing wrong.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In any programming language, you should try avoid doing string comparisons on dates entirely.

Just compare your dates to each other directly, or if you must, their numerical values.

You have fallen into a trap already in using date strings in that you are using '-' in one, and '/' in the other, which has a different ascii value, and therefore a different > < sort order. Also, the order mm-dd-yyyy instead of yyyy-mm-dd won't be helping things either when you need to range across different years.

Far better to steer clear of converting them in to strings for comparison at all in the first place.

Comment: You have a few console.log() s in your code, what do those look like in your console?

Comment: //var startDate = new Date(data[4]);

      var today = new Date();

Currently, you are only looking at today's date (not what is in your data set), so will either get all or nothing depending on your date range provided...